# Error Trying to Covert List<string> In Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using an asp.net api to query from my xamarin app to SQL Server.  Below is how I am querying the API, and setting up the return type, but I am getting an error of

> Can not convert List to List

What do I need to change in my code so that this will execute as desired?

```
public List<string> GetApprovalGrid()
{
    string URI = "XXXXXXX/api/Xamarin/properties";

    using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        var json = webClient.DownloadString(URI);

        var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);
        return message;
     }
}

public class ApproveUsers
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string lname { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string approveduser { get; set; }
}

private void LoadApproveUserGrid()
{
    List<ApproveUsers> ApprovedUser = new List<ApproveUsers>();
    //this line throws the error
    ApprovedUser = dal.GetApprovalGrid();
    //more code here
}
```

Comment: can you give us an example of what is returned by `var json = webClient.DownloadString(URI);`

Answer (score 1):

ApprovedUser is of type `List<ApproveUsers>` but GetApprovalGrid() returns `List<string>`

EDIT:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ApproveUsers>>(json);
```

if your json is correctly formatted

EDIT2: you need to change the method signature to this too:

```
public List<ApproveUsers> GetApprovalGrid()
```

Comment: this was my assumption with his question which is why I asked for an example of what hes actually returning.

Comment: if I set var message = to your above - then on the return message statement I get the same error.

Comment: @Loading - if I use your updated syntax I get this compile error - Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<XF_Login.Pages.ApproveUsers>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<XF_Login.ViewModels.ApproveUsers>'

Comment: it would be helpful if you could explain where this error happens. Your json result needs to be correct too

Comment: I am unable to get a copy of what the son looks like as I have multiple compile errors...this is the line of code that produces this error  ApprovedUser = dal.GetApprovalGrid();

Comment: Can you post your code? Its hard to help if i dont know what you did

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184420/discussion-between-doctor-ford-and-loading).

Comment: you can just plug your url into your brower to get the json

Comment: @Jason - I tried plugging directly into my browser but it does not return JSON it gives me No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

Comment: then are you sure that your json download in code is actually working?

Comment: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<XF_Login.Pages.ApproveUsers>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<XF_Login.ViewModels.ApproveUsers>' " This seems like you have two versions of the `ApproveUsers` type, one in namespace `XF_Login.Pages` and one in `XF_Login.ViewModels`. You may need to fully qualify your types.

Comment: @Jason - sorry you were correct, there was an issue with the API - now it is returning this   <ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<string>id</string>
<string>fname</string>
<string>lname</string>
<string>phone</string>
<string>company</string>
<string>approveduser</string>
</ArrayOfstring>

Comment: @jgoldberger - it seems that this is where the conflict is arising.  The button press event from a different page that will load the page above.`public async void OnApproveUsers()
{
    App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ApproveUsers()); 
    await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new ApproveUsers()); 
}`

Comment: that's XML, not JSON.  It's possible you can set a request header to get the API to return JSON, but if not your deserialization is not going to work

Comment: a). is the WebClient call returning XML or JSON?   b) in your OnApproveUsers() method, the last line is not needed.  c) the conflict is occuring because you have a page called ApproveUsers and a class called ApproveUsers.  You should renamed one of them for clarity, or properly qualify their namespaces to avoid the conflict

Comment: @Jason - b and c have been remedied.  How would I check if the WebClient API call is returning XML or JSON?

Comment: use the debugger to inspect the data that's returned.  Of just Debug.WriteLine it to the console

Comment: @Jason - value of var json that is returned is `["id","fname","lname","phone","company","approveduser"]`

Comment: that's JSON, but it's just a list of string values.  It's not data that corresponds to your ApproveUsers class.

Comment: I have the API call set to `        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            using (XamarinEntities entities = new XamarinEntities())
                return new string[] { "id", "fname", "lname", "phone", "company", "approveduser" };
        }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184434/discussion-between-doctor-ford-and-jason).